# Nilpotent groups: Need help understanding the construction of the upper central series.

Tags: group-theory

We are following Hungerford's text in class. The author writes:

> Let $G$ be a group. The center $C(G)$ of $G$ is a normal subgroup of $G$. Let $C_2(G)$ be the inverse image
>   of $C(G/C(G))$ under that canonical projection $G \to G/C(G)$. Then $C_2(G)$ is normal in G and contains $C(G)$...

I don't follow how $C(G) \le C_2(G)$.

Comment: $C(G)$ plays the role of the unit element in the quotient group, and the center of the quotient group contains the unit. Therefore the inverse image $C_2(G)$ contains $C(G)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

peter a g answer is correct. I will expand it here for you.

Denote by p the canonical projection and by $0_F$ the neutral element of G/C(G).

Notice that $ker(p)=C(G)$.

$p(C(G))=\{0_F\}\subset C(G/C(G))$.

Thus $C(G)\subset p^{-1}(C(G/C(G)))=C_2(G)$